# Under what conditions is there a common transversal?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graph-theory

Let $S = \{S_1,\dots,S_n\}$ and $T = \{T_1,\dots,T_n\}$ be two collections of finite subsets of $\{1,2,\dots\}$.

A transversal for $S$ is a list of elements $s_1,\dots,s_n$,
one coming from each set in $S$.  A common transversal is a single transversal for both
$S$ and $T$.

Under what conditions does a common transversal exist?  Why?

Comment: Is this a homework question? Please post any attempt you have already made.

Comment: No, this is not homework.  I am independently reading "Introduction to Graph Theory (4th ed)" by Robin J. Wilson.  On page 121 there is a sketch of a result on common transversals, but this sketch clearly contains some errors, as shown by some simple examples.  I want to know if anyone has other knowledge or a proof of a result about common transversals.

Comment: I'd be interested to see the mistaken result/sketch, as it might give some guidance to finding a correct one.